# PHP Crawling and Parsing (aspx)

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-crawler

I'm working on a project I have for my studies. I'm trying to combine economics and programming together by crawling through some public sites, and using that data to generate some sorts of economic reports.

I have managed to do all the sites I need, besides one. The site is written in C# (.aspx extension). And as far as my knowledge of HTTP requests it uses a POST request. All other sites I crawled were using GET requests (so that wasn't so hard).

The next part might be a bit confusing, but I would really appriciate if someone took a bit of their time and helped me :)

The site is on the following address:

- **http://www.apr.gov.rs/eng/Registers/FinancialLeasing.aspx**
- Select the option on the right **2. Search by leasing Acceptor**

The address of the page option 2 leads to is: **http://reliz.apr.gov.rs/Reliz/Search/GeneralLeasingAgreementLeaseeSearch.aspx** but if I use it directly it gives me **EXPIRED SESSION** error (so I guess that is one of the problems also)

This page now is on my native language (Serbian) so please bear with me just a bit longer.

Here:

- U need to select **Привредни субјект *** (second from 2 radio buttons)
- And below that **Матични број/Рег. бр., земља** (first check button)
- And then to enter for example **08010536** in the input field that appears after checking the button.
- And then press Enter or the button **Пронађи** that's on the far right.

After that a table appears at the bottom of the page. I need to get (crawl) data from that table, but I don't know how to make it appear with crawling :/
So far for crawling I have been using cUrl for php.

This is my final project at University, and i would appriciate any help or hint that i get.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the site's back-end code is written in. If you're scraping, then you're dealing with HTML. Doesn't matter WHAT spit out that html... it's just html when it reaches your client.

Comment: It looks like you can do a POST request to `GeneralLeasingAgreementLeaseeSearch.aspx` with the fields that you see in the form. Just look at the source of that page...